# Count down timer php displays time left

Tags: php, html, countdown

How could I set a date and get a countdown in PHP?

For example  I want it to say:

> toplist resets in x days x hours x minutes x seconds

The toplist resets on the 1st of every month.

Here is a photo of what I would like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, get the number of seconds until the deadline. So that will output something like:

```
752200
```

Which means, `752200` seconds until the deadline.

In the client side, try to use a timer plugin, like [Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/):

```
<div id="getting-started"></div>
```

```
$("#getting-started")
.countdown({
  seconds: // get the value from PHP
}, function(event) {
  $(this).text(
    event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this , ill have a look through this now, and ill mark as answered when timer lets me . Thanks again

Comment: forgot to ask, how will this work on the reset? So , lets say it displays as " resets in 2 days " , after the 1st comes around, will the reset counter, reset? so it says " toplist resets in 30 days" ect

Comment: Yeah... Right, check out the documentation [here](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html).